# newline charter \n gives "java.sql.SQLException: ORA-00911: invalid character\n" Oracle 11g

Tags: java, sql, oracle, jdbc, oracle11g

I have Oracle DB 11g Enterprise Edition and I want to create a table by reading the sql script from a file.Through java code I am reading following sql script from a file and storing it in a `String sqlBlock`:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE VerHist_SeqNum
   START WITH 1 
   INCREMENT BY 1;
CREATE TABLE VerHist
(
  SequenceNumber NUMBER(10,0)  NOT NULL,
  SQLFileName VARCHAR2(100)  NOT NULL,
  STATUS VARCHAR2(10)  NOT NULL,
  AppliedDate DATE  NOT NULL,
  DateCreated DATE 
   DEFAULT (SYSDATE),
  DateUpdated DATE 
   DEFAULT (SYSDATE),
  CONSTRAINT PK_VerHist PRIMARY KEY( SequenceNumber ),
  CONSTRAINT UC_VerHist_SQLFileNa UNIQUE( SQLFileName )
);
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER VerHist_SeqNum_TRG
   BEFORE INSERT 
   ON VerHist
   FOR EACH ROW
   BEGIN
      SELECT VerHist_SeqNum.NEXTVAL INTO :NEW.SequenceNumber
        FROM DUAL;
   END;
```

When I execute this query it gives

> **java.sql.SQLException: ORA-00911: invalid character\n**
>     at
>   oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:112)
>     at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:331)    at
>   oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:288)     at
>   oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.receive(T4C8Oall.java:743)    at
>   oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CStatement.doOall8(T4CStatement.java:207)    at
>   oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CStatement.executeForRows(T4CStatement.java:946)
>     at
>   oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStatement.java:1168)
>     at
>   oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.executeInternal(OracleStatement.java:1687)
>     at
>   oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.execute(OracleStatement.java:1653)

Following is my code to execute the sql block:

```
Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
String sqlBlock = //"this contains the content of the file (it contains \n charters)";
stmt.execute(sqlBlock);
```

Is the newline charter invalid here, if yes, how to get this working otherwise?

Please note that when I copy paste the contents of this file and run the script through *Oracle SQL Developer* it runs fine.

Comment: why you have \n characters? remove them...

Comment: try to use escape character means \\n  in place of \n

Comment: I tried replacing `\n`with single space, also tried `\\n` instead of `\n` but still getting the same error message.

Comment: then please post the original code of that sql-block

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I think the `\n` reference is a red-herring, and an artefact of how the error is being logged. You're trying to run two SQL statements, separated by a semi-colon, in one `execute`. That is not allowed. The semi-colon is a statement separator in SQL*Plus, not in SQL, and will generate an ORA-00911 even with a single statement. And `execute` has to be a single statement.

If you were doing DML you could wrap the statements in a PL/SQL block and execute that, but since this is DDL you can't do that unless you resort to dynamic SQL, which is going to be overly complicated and messy for what you're trying to do.

You need to put each statement in a separate file (without the trailing semi-colon on the `create sequence`; you still need it on the `create trigger` because there it is ending the trigger's PL/SQL block, not acting as a statement separator - confusing, I know), and read and execute them separately. Then each `execute` has a single statement, and will be much happier.

---

As an aside, you don't need to select your sequence value into your variable in 11g; [you can now do it like this](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/whatsnew.htm#LNPLS117):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER VerHist_SeqNum_TRG
BEFORE INSERT 
ON VerHist
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  :NEW.SequenceNumber := VerHist_SeqNum.NEXTVAL;
END;
```

Comment: Thanks Alex, your solution worked +1. Pardon my lack of knowledge in Oracle and SQL in general, could you please let me know how my sql statement will change as per your last suggestion about variable in 11g.

Comment: Is the semicolon here `:NEW.SequenceNumber := VerHist_SeqNum.NEXTVAL;`optional? can I remove it? asking this because I have changed my java code to think SQL statement ends with semicolon.

Comment: @John - no, it isn't optional there, and the one after the `END` isn't optional either. The `BEGIN`/`END` is a PL/SQL block, which can itself contain multiple semicolon-separated statements, and the block has to be terminated by a semicolon. In that context that is not a statement separator. This is... confusing. For the driver, everything from `CREATE` to `END;` is one statement. It would probably be better to omit the semicolon form the `create sequence` file, rather than try to make Java figure out when to strip it. The code in the file will still run in SQL Developer.

Comment: Oh, so If I want to keep all the SQL statement in one file then what can be used as a separator for these SQL statements, if not semicolon ?

Comment: So you can load one file into Java and then have that split it into statements? I'd use `/`, which would be still work in SQL Developer ([or SQL*Plus](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/ch_twelve004.htm)). Parsing a file into statements might give you headaches at some point though, e.g. if the file has comments in it (`/* ... */`). Separate files would be simpler to manage I think, if more work in Java.

Comment: I had the same issue. Turns out my query string had the ; at the end! :-O Silly me!

Answer (score 0):

When you copy paste the contains of the file to browser. Browser will treat \n as new line.
Whereas for the code /n is character only.
Try to replace \n with single space and then run it will work

Comment: I tried replacing `\n`with single space, but still getting the same error message.

Comment: @John could you please add code which explains how you have read the file

Answer (score 0):

`sqlBlock = sqlBlock.replaceAll("\n"," ");`

Remove the \n from the query. If you want the query to be formatted in sql developer, you can select the query and press Ctrl+F7

Comment: Can you paste the entire statement instead of
`String sqlBlock = //"this contains the content of the file (it contains \n charters)";`